# php отправка письма на email

Tags: php

Есть такой код страницы корзины. Как подправить содержимое письма чтобы данные отображались корректно? На мыло при отправке какая-то чухня приходит))

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            foreach($_POST['quanity'] as $key => $val) {
                if($val==0) {
                    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quanity']=$val;
                }
            }
        }

    ?>

    <h1>View Cart</h1>

    <a href="index.php?page=products">Go back to products page</a>


        <form method="post" name="tab" action="index.php?page=cart">
            <table>
                <tr> 
                    <th>Name</th> 
                    <th>Quanity</th> 
                    <th>Price</th> 
                    <th>Items Price</th> 
                </tr>

                <?php
                    require("includes/connection.php");
                    $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN(";
                    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
                        $sql.=$id.",";
                    }
                    $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
                    $query=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                    $totalprice=0;
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
                        $subtotal=$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quanity']*$row['price']; 
                        $totalprice+=$subtotal;
                ?>

                    <tr> 
                        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td> 
                        <td><input type="text" name="quanity[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quanity'] ?>" /></td> 
                        <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?>$</td> 
                        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quanity']*$row['price'] ?>$</td> 
                    </tr> 

                <?php
                    }
                ?>

                <tr> 
                    <td colspan="4">Total Price: <?php echo $totalprice ?></td> 
                </tr> 
            </table>

            <br/>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Cart</button> 

            <input type="text" name="fio" placeholder="Укажите ФИО">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Укажите e-mail">
            <button type="submit" name="order">Отправить</button>
        </form>


    <?php
        require("includes/connection.php");
                    $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN(";
                    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
                        $sql.=$id.",";
                    }
                    $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
                    $query=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                    $totalprice=0;
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
                        $subtotal=$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quanity']*$row['price']; 
                        $totalprice+=$subtotal;
        if(isset($_POST['order'])){
            $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
            $headers .= 'From: Your name <info@address.com>' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            $content='
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <tr> 
                    <td>' .$row["name"]. '</td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="quanity[' .$row["id"]. ']" size="5" value="' .$_SESSION["cart"][$row["id"]]["quanity"]. '" /></td> 
                    <td>' .$row["price"]. '$</td> 
                    <td>' .$_SESSION["cart"][$row["id"]]["quanity"]*$row["price"]. '$</td> 
                </tr> 
            </body>
            </html>
            ';

            $message = $_POST['fio'].$content;
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
            mail($_POST['email'], 'My Subject', $message, $headers);
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$content');</script>";
        }
    ?>




    <br /> 
    <p>To remove an item, set it's quanity to 0. </p>
```

Comment: Вопрос частично решен, но приходит только один товар и без общей цены)) где ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю так

```
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: СИСТЕМНОЕ УВЕДОМЛЕНИЕ  <sistem@domen.ru>\r\n"; 
 $headers.="Content-type:text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"";
 $headers .= "Bcc: sistem@domen.ru\r\n";
```

Попробуйте кодировку utf-8